# If then statement compile error in VB Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This is my vba code I’m facing the above error but I am unable to understand where the problem lies.

```
Sub If_Loop()
Dim cell As Range

For each cell in Range(“Sheet3”)

If cell.Value > 4400 and cell.Value < 8500 Then cell.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbGreen

End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, how’d you do that? I’m on my mobile so it is not as easy.

Comment: Four spaces before a line of code will format it as code. Or put three backticks ``` before and after the code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `If` statement is on one line, like this

```
If cell.Value > 4400 and cell.Value < 8500 Then cell.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbGreen
```

you don't need the `End If`

you only need `End If` when it's like this

```
If cell.Value > 4400 and cell.Value < 8500 Then
   cell.Interior.Color = VBA.ColorConstants.vbGreen
End If
```

check [If...Then...Else statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement) docs.

And please, note the remark:

> You can use the single-line form (first syntax) for short, simple
> tests. However, the block form (second syntax) provides more structure
> and flexibility than the single-line form and is usually easier to
> read, maintain, and debug.

I would suggest to refactor your code and use the block form (i.e. multi-line with `End If`)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a named range called "Sheet3"?  I'd guess that's your worksheet name?

Also you're using the single-line `If-Then`, so the `End If` would not be needed.
Might be clearer to split it up:

```vb
Sub If_Loop()
    Dim cell As Range
    
    For each cell in Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:E100").Cells 'for example
        If cell.Value > 4400 and cell.Value < 8500 Then 
             cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Tim, however I’m stilling getting the same error. 
Compile error: End If without block If

Comment: The exact code I posted runs fine for me - no compile-time or runtime errors.